# pandas select by value fails withnot supported between instances

Tags: pandas

in this easy example I create a dataframe with number values but can't select by values of numbers

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    ['a', 5, 9],
    ['b', 4, 61],
    ['c', 24, 9]]),
    columns=['name', 'attr11', 'attr12'])
```

this

```
df1[df1.attr12 > 10]
```

with

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

can anyone explain why and how I would correctly select rows with numbers above 10 ?

Comment: get rid of `np.array()` constructor for data lists, as it implies unified dtype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By defining your DataFrame with a numpy array, all the dtypes are string.

You must manually convert to integer:

```
df1 = df1.astype({'attr11': int, 'attr12': int})
```

Or use a nested list or dictionary to define your DataFrame:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 5, 9],
                    ['b', 4, 61],
                    ['c', 24, 9]],
                   columns=['name', 'attr11', 'attr12'])

# or
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                    'attr11': [5, 4, 21],
                    'attr12': [9, 61, 9],
                   })
```

Then your code will work as expected.

Comment: thanks for that. not sure which convention I like more